# redirect output of every process to a text file

Tags: c, redirect, output, stdout

hi im trying to redirect my standard output of every process to a seperate file.
i have tried however it doesn't seem to be working or i can only print the first process to a text file.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main()
{
    int fd[2];
    pid_t pid2, pid1;
    int file1 = open("output1.txt", O_CREAT|O_TRUNC |O_RDWR, 0664);
    int file2 = open("output2.txt", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0664);

    //fd1 write, fd0 read
    if(pipe(fd) == -1)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    pid1 = fork();
    if (pid1 < 0)
    {
        return 2;
    }
    if (pid1 == 0)
    {
        //child process 1
        dup2(fd[1], 1);
        close(fd[0]);
        execlp("ls", "ls", "-l", NULL);
       
     //   close(fd[1]);
    }
    else
    {
        pid2 = fork();
        if (pid2 < 0)
        {
            return 3;
        }
        close(fd[1]);

        if (pid2 == 0)
        {
                char buf[100];
            ssize_t bytesread;

           // int file2 = open("output2.txt", O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0664);
            close(fd[1]); //close write end 

            //child process 2
            // use execvp
            dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        

            while ((bytesread = read(fd[0], buf, 100)) > 0) {
                write(file1, buf, bytesread);
            }

            lseek(file1, (off_t) 0, SEEK_SET);
            dup2(file1, 0);
            execlp("grep", "grep", "extest", NULL);

            // above code prints to text file.
        }
    }
    close(fd[0]);
    close(fd[1]);
    waitpid(pid1, NULL, 0);
    waitpid(pid2, NULL, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

this is my code.
the pipe  is supposed to run ls then grep will search for all results in the ls result.
i want ls (process 1) output to be directed to a text file which works  called output1.txt then process 2 will be redirected to output2 but i cant figure out for to redirect p2.

any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Should the childs terminate after executing `ls` / `grep`?

Comment: @Gerhardh the child process terminated after  ls then the parent creates another child to execute grep

Comment: Well, in case of an error `execlp` returns and then your child will also continue to second `fork`.